# Usar Git en red local, con varios colaboradores

Tags: eclipse, git

Estoy usando eclipse Photon y trabajo en el plugin de eGit para el control de versiones. Trabajando individualmente no tengo problema, pero ahora necesito que otros colaboradores en la red local de la empresa también pueden acceder a mi repositorio para colaborar en le desarrollo, la preguntas son :

- ¿Debo configurar o descargar algo extra en Eclipse?
- ¿Puedo controlar quien entra a colaborar en el codigo ?
- No puedo usar herramientas online (de ahi que no use Github)
- Los otros colaboradores no son profesionales de TI , por ello necesito que los cambios lo hagan desde la interfaz intuitiva que proporciona el plugin de eGit de eclipse, no desde una terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te cuento mi experiencia: Yo tenía un problema similar en mi trabajo, la cual no tenía el control del versiones de código (Por lo cual se le dificultaba al área de desarrollo), para solucionar dicho problema se investigó implementar un [servidor de GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Poniendo-Git-en-un-Servidor). la cual tuvo mucho éxito, sin embargo nuestro requerimiento era crear un ambiente de Desarrollo Continuo (Como por ejemplo: manejar los repositorios de trabajo a partir de permisos y pull Requests, tal como GITHUB).

El servidor de Git nos daba la base para desarrollar dicho requerimiento, sin embargo se requiere tiempo... Por lo cual seguimos investigando y encontramos una herramienta Open Source llamada, [GOGS](https://gogs.io/). Herramienta desarrollada en el lenguaje GO (Google), con las carácterísticas similares de un servidor de git (GS), esta herramienta es muy similar al GITHUB y te brinda lo siguiente:

- Manejo de Usuarios (Por el prototipo, SSH o HTTP)
- Interfaz web y visual para manejar los repositorios
- Control de Pull Requests
- Manejo de WIKI (Documentación de repositorios)
- Manejo de incidencia en repositorios
- Manejo de Hooks
- Entre otras cosas más...

Dicha herramienta, nos ayudó bastante... Espero que lo puedas implementar en tu ambiente de trabajo (Solo sigue las instrucciones de la documentación de [GOGS](https://gogs.io/docs)), y lo mejor de todo es OPEN SOURCE.

Saludos.